Can't install Python Pylint on Windows 10
I can't seem to get Pylint to install on my Work PC, trying to figure out if it is a Network issue or something else. Below is the output when I try using "pip install pylint"
C:\Python312>pip -V
pip 23.2.1 from C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

C:\Python312>pip install pylint
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AB8013A40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pylint/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AB7D58FB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pylint/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AB8069B80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pylint/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AB8069CD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pylint/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AB8069E80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pylint/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylint (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylint

C:\Python312>


If you run pip install pylint -v to get verbose output, do you get any new info?

Just tried that and I get the same output.
